# Change the name of the Wi-Fi hotspot

Tags: wifi-hotspot

Device: Samsung Galaxy Note 3

The wireless tethering hotspot name is `AndroidAP`. I would like to change this if I can.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4, but you should have something similar to this: `System settings > Connections > More Networks > Tethering and portable hotspot > Portable Wi-Fi hotspot`.

[image]

If you don't see Configure button (not visible on my S4 5.0.1), try pressing device Menu button while you are at the Mobile Hotspot settings page (which shows your hotspot name and password)

Comment: I don't seem to see a place to rename like you do. Here is what I see under tethering and portable hotspot: http://imgur.com/stE9HIM. Under More Networks: http://imgur.com/PSQWMbL. And finally under connections: http://imgur.com/UmlIDyr

Comment: Oh, now I see! I tap on "Portable Wifi Hotspot" and I then see the screen that allows me to configure it! I was confused because the on/off switch on that line looked like it was the only control for that line, instead of also being able to tap on it and enter another screen. Thank you very much!

Comment: This option no longer exists in Lollipop.  However, from this [forum](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s4/588032-can-t-change-wifi-hotspot-settings-after-upgrade-lollipop-5-0-1-a.html) I discovered that the configuration has been hidden unless you hit the menu button ("recent key") on the bottom left of the phone (opposite side as the the back button).  Who decides to make cryptic changes like this?!

Comment: Oh man!  @JessRiedel I have been searching for so long for this.  I'm with you: who makes stupid changes like this!?    It would be worth a separate answer to this question with this information, I nearly missed your comment altogether!